# Getting undefined in innerHTML when fetching and displaying data from database using AJAX and JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

This is the script I have written for fetching data from the database using AJAX.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadJSON()
{
   var data_file = "http://www.idesigns.com.pk/comingsoon/test/connect.php";
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
             var jsonObj = xmlhttp.responseText;
             document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML =  jsonObj.firstname;
             document.getElementById("lastname").innerHTML = jsonObj.lastname; 
             document.getElementById("ajaxDiv").innerHTML=jsonObj;

        }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET", data_file, true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<title>JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>User Details</h1>
<p id="firstname">John</p>
<p id="lastname">Doe</p>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadJSON()">Update Details </button>
</body>
</html>
```

No error in database connection.
no error in fetching and/or in echo of JSON object.
But when I try to display the data using innerHTML, I am getting the following output with undefined instead of getting firstname and lastname from the object.

**OUTPUT:**

```
undefined

undefined

{"id":"1","firstname":"Bruce","lastname":"Lee"}
```

I can't figure out what's happening. So if anyone can help? Please

Comment: What do you get when you print the `jsonObj`?

Comment: This is what I am getting {"id":"1","firstname":"Bruce","lastname":"Lee"}

Comment: @AkshatSinghal: It was actually there, you had to look pretty closely to see it. :-) Semir's edit helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use the string as though it were a deserialized object. The string doesn't have properties called `firstname` and `lastname`.

You need to decode the string into an object:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Then your code using `jsonObj.firstname` and such will work. (Note that at that point, it *isn't* a "JSON object." It's just an object. JSON is a *textual* notation; once the text is parsed, you're not dealing with JSON anymore.)

Comment: If I use<br/>var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);                        then I am getting this error in my console.<br/>XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.idesigns.com.pk/comingsoon/test/connect.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://idesigns.com.pk' is therefore not allowed access.<br/>And it's doing nothing.

Comment: The reason I was getting error in my google chrome console is because the (www.) was missing from my URL in the address bar.

Comment: @MuhammadAftab: it will be nice to use the JSON.parse fallback for ie 5, 6. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON first. Your `responseText` is just one great big string, so when you try to access a property like `responseText.firstname` it comes back as `undefined` because strings have no `firstname` property. Use this:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse( xmlhttp.responseText );
```

Now `jsonObj` should be an object, not a string, with properties corresponding to the data your server sent.

Comment: If I use<br/>var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); then I am getting this error in my console.<br/>XMLHttpRequest cannot load idesigns.com.pk/comingsoon/test/connect.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'idesigns.com.pk'; is therefore not allowed access.<br/>And it's doing nothing.

Comment: The reason I was getting error in my google chrome console is because the (www.) was missing from my URL in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
xmlhttp.responseType = "json"
```

and change your code accordingly. Dont treat your response as Text when it is a JSON object